# Problem with receiving message from Azure service bus in Azure databricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azureservicebus

I've got a problem with receiving a message from azure service bus queue in azure databricks, can't establish a connection with service bus queue from azure databricks notebook using python.

When using normal code without specifying the TransportType I'm getting given error, so suspecting either ports are closed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hDwj.png)

So I tried specifying TransportType to transport_type=TransportType.AmqpOverWebsocket in the from_connection_string to change the port, but then I'm getting a strange error that 'str' object has no attribute 'AmqpOverWebsocket', please see the error below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl3kb.png)

Any help would be amazing, thanks in advance!

I tried changing the transportType attribute to AmqpOverWebsocket, but next error occured. I verified that the queue is up and running, functions normally in azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection string itself add ";TransportType=AmqpWebSockets".

Original Connection String - Endpoint=sb://<>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<>

Modified Connection String -
Endpoint=sb://<>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<>;TransportType=AmqpWebSockets

Comment: Hey, tried this one, and I'm back to point one, again getting Unable to open authentication session on connection 'my_connection', Please confirm target hostname exists: 'my_host'. Do you think it's something wrong with the firewall or access level?

Comment: Most likely yes, it may be a firewall issue. In our environment service fabric is one of the compute and we have HTTPS outbound is open so we can connect when we use AmqpWebSockets. If your network has restricted gateway then it may be an issue. With AmqpWebSockets alll traffic should go to 443 port, but gateways can have host restrictions. What kind of compute you are rerunning? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq Look for question. Look for question “ What ports do I need to open on the firewall?”